# Typecast to an int in Octave/Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, octave, casting

I need to call the index of a matrix made using the linspace command, and based on some data taken from an oscilloscope.  Because of this, the data inputed is a double.  However, I can't really call:

```
Time[V0Found]
```

where V0Found is something like 5.2 however, taking index 5 is close enough, so I need to drop the decimal.  I used this equation to drop the decimal:

```
V0FoundDec = V0Found - mod(V0Found,1)
Time[V0FoundDec]
```

However, even though that drops the decimal, octave still complains about it.

So, what can I do to typecast it to an int?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MATLAB, it should be `int8(x)` or `int16(x)` or [one of the other integer casts](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk_r13/help/techdoc/ref/int8.html).

But I'm surprised you need to do that for an index. Try

```
myarray(floor(indexlist))
```

or

```
myarray(round(indexlist))
```

where `myarray` is your array and `indexlist` is your vector of noninteger indices.

---

example:

```
octave-3.2.3:8> v=rand(1,8)*10+1
v =

   3.1769   1.4397   8.7504   1.7424   6.9413   3.1663   8.4085   9.0179

octave-3.2.3:9> a = (1:1:20).^2
a =

 Columns 1 through 15:

     1     4     9    16    25    36    49    64    81   100   121   144   169   196   225

 Columns 16 through 20:

   256   289   324   361   400

octave-3.2.3:10> a(floor(v))
ans =

    9    1   64    1   36    9   64   81
```

Comment: You're idea does work, although it didn't work in the script, I'm guessing I must have just had a really small value for X.

Answer (score 2):

You could use *round*, *floor*, *ceil* functions instead of your formula to do the rounding.

By the way, indexing is done using parenthesis instead of brackets so:

```
V0FoundDec = round(V0Found);
Time(V0FoundDec) % not Time[V0FoundDec]
```

In case that was your problem

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab, the right way to do this is to use the `interp1` function to interpolate.  The format of this command is

```
yout = interp1 (xdata, ydata, xin, ...)
```

or

```
yout = interp1 (ydata, xin, ...)
```

where `xdata` is then assumed to be `1:length(ydata)`.

If you want to produce the result you would get from calling

```
V0FoundDec = Time(round(V0found))
```

you would say

```
V0FoundDec = interp1(Time, V0found, 'nearest')
```

but you can just as easily get linear interpolation (this is the default) with

```
V0FoundDec = interp1(Time, V0found)
```

or

```
V0FoundDec = interp1(Time,V0found,'linear')
```

and you can also extrapolate outside the limits (using 'extrap' or providing an `extrap` value), where

```
Time(round(V0found))
```

will crash if `round(V0found) < 1` or `> length(Time)`

Answer (score 1):

For those using Octave, the [cast](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/cast.html) function does the job:

```
octave:1> cast(5.2,'int8')
ans = 5
```

Comment: That is the same as `int8(5.2)`. The string argument for the type is useful in some cases, but not necessary in this one. That said, casting to integer is not necessary for indexing, `round()` or `floor()` suffice.

Comment: Well, I thought so too. Before coming here I had a situation where `A(floor(double),:)` did not work, but did work with `cast`, and I thought it could help others.